# In Oriental Orthodox sacramental theology can a mixed marriage be valid?

Tags: marriage, sacraments, oriental-orthodox

The Armenians and Syriac allow mixed marriages with trinitarian christians. But generally only the orthodox can take sacraments . How is such a mixed marriage valid then?

Answer (score 1):

From [The Sacrament of Holy Crowning in the Armenian Apostolic Orthodox Church](https://holytrinity-pa.org/the-rite-of-crowning-in-marriage/)

> Today, this Eucharistic tradition is confronted with many challenges.
> In our pluralistic society the great diversity of religious faith
> confessions makes the “ideal” of a marriage between Armenian Orthodox
> partners less a reality in the Church community. The Church now
> encounters the condition of a “mixed marriage”; a marriage between an
> Armenian Orthodox and a Christian from another faith confession. Such
> situations do not change the general meaning of marriage with regard
> to its intent but certainly present problems when celebrating the
> rites of blessing.
>
> It should be understood that mixed marriages are neither encouraged
> nor forbidden by the Armenian Orthodox Church. Sacramental blessing by
> the church granted through the person of the officient Priest could
> only be administered and celebrated for those who are baptized
> Christians. Canonically there is no separate liturgical rite for an
> Armenian Orthodox and a non- Christian.
>
> As stated, mixed marriages are those between Armenian Orthodox and
> persons from Christian confessions that acknowledge belief in the Holy
> Trinity and the Divinity of Jesus Christ as Lord and Saviour. The
> celebration of the Sacrament of Crowning, as it is traditionally
> called, is allowed for a mixed faith union out of concern for the
> couple’s well being inviting them both to share in prayer and affirm,
> however possible, their common faith within the rite without
> compromise of personal or Church integrity. This practice of
> “oekonomia” thus allows both to share as much as possible. It should
> remain clear that the acceptance and participation of a non-Armenian
> Orthodox Christian in the marriage rite does not imply his/her
> conversion nor does it grant him/her the privilege to actively receive
> the other Sacraments of the Church. It is only by the Sacrament of
> Chrismation that one becomes a member of the faith community; after
> proper catechizes before or after marriage.

Arguably, this is a palliative measure as a consequence of declining religiosity in Europe. The same phenomenon can be identified for other denominations in many European countries with low religiosity:

[image]

(Pew Research)

Which clearly reflects in the proportion of mixed marriages:

[image]

From [Mixed Marriages in Europe, 1990-2010](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258210005_Mixed_Marriages_in_Europe_1990-2010)